# What are needed in the computer server for deploying ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I'm kinda new in building web application using ASP.NET MVC, and I'm planning on deploying my application on the server. And my question is what things are
needed to be installed in the server so that my ASP.NET web app can run?

I've listed some few things:

1. ASP.NET Framework 4
2. SQL Server 2008
3. IIS as web server
4. ASP.NET MVC 3
5. ASP.NET Web Pages

Any other things I need to install in my server? And the app that I'm building is a multi user app (around 100 users), what is the recommended specification for the server?

Thanks for your response!

Comment: Although this isn't specifically about code, the problem is the same: What are you trying to solve? Why is asking us more advantageous than deploying it and seeing what doesn't work? There's no '1 size fits all' deployment for ASP.NET MVC; it all depends on what your application needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, most of what you listed is incorrect. All you need to run is IIS with ASP.NET feature installed, and .NET (which is either there by default or installed when setting up IIS).

SQL Server may be necessary, but should *not* be installed on the same server. Both IIS and SQL Server will attempt to use all available system RAM in order to do their job (they don't cap memory usage). Therefore, in all but the most beastly server configs, they're going to step on each other's toes.

MVC/Web Pages comes along for the ride when your publish your app. They get compiled as DLLs into your application.

Other than that, it's just down to specs of your servers, which is virtually impossible to detail without an intimate understanding of your app and environment (i.e. only you can know). I can say that you'll need at least 4GB of ram for each of your web server and SQL server. Though, 8GB would be much more reasonable. I'd recommend using fast hard drive 7200 RPM minimum for a platter-style drive, but given that IIS and SQL Server both rely on the filesystem heavily, an SSD or enterprise-class platter drive (15,000+ RPM) would be better.